# How to get ASCII code in ax register instead of Scan code

Tags: assembly, emu8086, dosbox

I'm making a program which prints the key which is pressed on the keyboard using keyboard hardware interrupts, the code I have written prints the value against the scan code of the character when the key is down.
when using `int 16h` , `ah = 01h`
the program is to return
AH = BIOS scan code
AL = ASCII character
but it is not, here is my code that i did so far..

the ASCII codes are no where in `al` or `ah`, now I have heard that I need to get them from BIOS or it has to do something with ISR and PIC board something...

```
[org 100h]
jmp start

kbisr:
push ax
push es
mov ax,0xb800
mov es,ax
in al,0x60

cmp cl, 0
je keypress
jmp keyrelease

keyrelease:
mov cl, 0
jmp nomatch

keypress:
; need changes here i guess..
mov cl, 1
add al,67
and al,01111111b
mov byte[es:3600],al
jmp nomatch

nomatch:
mov al,0x20
out 0x20,al
pop es
pop ax
add di,2
iret

start:
mov di,0
xor ax,ax
mov es,ax
cli
mov word[es:9*4],kbisr
mov [es:9*4+2],cs
sti
l1:
jmp l1
```

should print 'a' when a is pressed 'b' when b is pressed and so on..
currently its set to prints 'a' when a is pressed prints 'b' when s is pressed prints 'c' when d is pressed and so on... because these are scan codes in a line I am guessing

Comment: Last time I saw this done the code did include its own scan code to character mapping. I guess DOS has its own mapping loaded somewhere but I'm not sure where to find that sorry.

Comment: hmm i get your point, im sure it has that like any built in function.
but lets say what i need is either a function to convert it myself or get ascii in ax instead of scan code directly from bios by something called intrupt chaining

Comment: Your question is confusing: I don't see any [`INT 16h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm) calls in it at all. But you're trying to get some data from the keyboard port with `IN AL, 60h`. So have a look at [this OSDev article](https://wiki.osdev.org/Babystep5) which may give you some inpiration on how to handle the result of the `IN AL, 60h`.

Comment: It is the keyboard interrupt handler that converts the keyboard input into scan code and character code. Why would the DOS or BIOS provide a translation service for someone who by-passes their keyboard functions and reads directly from the keyboard port?